# Find in page that's iOS compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I'm trying to set up a "find in page" that is compatible with iOS, and so far the only option I found is using the Find in Page bookmarklet. The problem is that this requires someone to past that code into their browser address bar and his submit...

```
void(s = prompt('Find text:', ''));
s = '('
s ')';
x = new RegExp(s, 'gi');
rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
rid = 'z'
rn;
b = document.body.innerHTML;
b = b.replace(x, '<span name='
rid ' id='
rid ' style=\'color:#000;background-color:yellow; font-weight:bold;\'>$1</span>');
void(document.body.innerHTML = b);
alert('Found '
document.getElementsByName(rid).length ' matches.');
window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementsByName(rid)[0].offsetTop);
```

Ideally, there would be a way to enter text into a text box, hit submit, and it runs the code...

```
<input type="text" id="find" />
<button type="submit" id="submit" />
```

I'm not sure how you would do something like that, or if it's even possible. Some clarification will be appreciated. Also, jQuery is an available language if that would make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't use the find on page that's already built into mobile safari?

Comment: Yes, there us a nav bar in this web app which always stays at the top of the page, and I want the search always visible. And I don't like how the find in page works on Mobile Safari.